# inverse of homographic function $f\left( x \right) = \frac{{ax + b}}{{cx + d}}$

Tags: calculus, analysis

I know that for homographic function $f\left( x \right) = \frac{{ax + b}}{{cx + d}}$, when its inverse is not coincide with it, $f(x)$ and ${f^{ - 1}}\left( x \right)$ have common points only on line $y=x$, on the other hand it is well known that when a function is not strictly increasing a function and its inverse may have a common point that is not on $y=x$, but i don't know why this can not happen for homographic function and what is the geometric interpretation of this.

Answer (score 1):

Every homographic function is equivalent to $f(x)=ax$ or $f(x)=x+b.$ If $a\ne0$ and $a\ne1$ then if $f\ne f^{-1}$  they have common value only $f(0)=f^{-1}(0)=0$ and $\infty$, both on $y=x$. If $b\ne0$ then the only common value is $f(\infty)=f^{-1}(\infty)=\infty$. In both cases, the graph of $f$ is a straignt line and if for some $x,y$ we have $f(x)=y, f(y)=x$ then $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)=-x$.